# Messed up keybinding on Gentoo

Tags: linux, keyboard, xorg, gentoo

After I installed some updates on my Gentoo system some Keybindings are messed up. I didn't make a note which packages - so I cannot provide a list. The only thing I remember is that I installed x11-drivers/xf86-input-keyboard and x11-drivers/xf86-input-mouse.

If I push the "arrow down" button the event is:

```
Mapping

Notify event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 248

KeyRelease event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0xb4, subw 0x0, time 1077864, (428,325), root:(432,404),
    state 0x0, keycode 116 (keysym 0xff54, Down), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

MappingNotify event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 248

KeyRelease event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0xb4, subw 0x0, time 1077864, (428,325), root:(432,404),
    state 0x0, keycode 104 (keysym 0xff8d, KP_Enter), same_screen YES,
"   XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0d) "
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

(output of xev). It's like clicking "arrow down" and then "enter".

The same goes with pushing the "delete" Button: It's like clicking the "print screen" button and then "delete". I've no idea where to search for this kind of problem.

I hope one of you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update would be [`hal-info`](http://hal.freedesktop.org/quirk/quirk-keymap-index.html).

Comment: Ok it was the right hint. The problem was that hal disturbed with evdev somehow. I unmerged hal and now everything works just like it has to.